# Removing everything after the period in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame that has gene ID's listed as such:

```
df <- c(ENSG000012345.12, ENSG00004684.45, ENSG0000046858.45, ENSG000005768.3, ENSG00000675.5)
```

I am trying to write a command that will remove everything after the period. So, that I end up with:

```
df <- c(ENSG000012345, ENSG00004684, ENSG0000046858, ENSG000005768, ENSG00000675)
```

My actual data frame has around 20,000 gene names, this is just a small snippet. If someone could help me with this that would be great!

Comment: `sub("\\..*","",df)`

Comment: Is there a way for me to do this and get the results as one long column as opposed to a vector? I tried doing ````as.data.frame```` but that does not work.